# Non-const reference bound to temporary, Visual Studio bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, temporary-objects

I ran into this while compiling some portable code in `gcc`. Basically this strange code compiles in Visual studio which really just blows my mind:

```
class Zebra {int x;};
Zebra goo() {Zebra z; return z;}
void foo(Zebra &x)
{
    Zebra y;
    x = y;
    foo(goo());
}
```

`Visual studio` lets this one fly. `gcc` will catch this as a compile error.  Interestingly, If you typedef Zebra to int, `VC++` will complain.  Quite contradictory behavior.  Thoughts?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a compiler extension, and an evil one at that.

Comment: MSVC does have `warning C4239: nonstandard extension used`, but apparently you have that warning turned off.

Comment: I don't see why you needed to use an infinitely recursing function to demo this.

Answer (score 24):

This is old extension to Visual Studio, the only reference I could find on the Microsoft site was this bug report: [Temporary Objects Can be Bound to Non-Const References](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807118/temporary-objects-can-be-bound-to-non-const-references), which has the following example code:

```
struct A {};

A     f1();
void f2(A&);

int main()
{
    f2(f1()); // This line SHALL trigger an error, but it can be compiled without any     errors or warnings.
}
```

One of the responses notes:

> There is a level 4 warning (level 4 warning are enabled if you pass /W4 to the compiler) for it

This blog post: [Visual C++ is so Liberal](http://www.asawicki.info/news_1482_visual_c_is_so_liberal.html) which covers this extension notes that:

> Using Disable Language Extensions (/Za) makes it an error:

Answer (score 10):

As others said, this is due to Microsoft C++ extension. Though `/Za` flag is not recommended as it can break things.

Instead use the `/permissive-`  switch for better standards compliancy and you will get healthy errors for these cases. Note that this flag is available since VS 2017.

> The switch /Za does not support certain key Microsoft SDK header files. By contrast /permissive- offers a useful conformance mode where input C++ code is interpreted according to ISO C++ rules but also allows conforming extensions necessary to compile C++ on targets supported by Visual C++.

More info is on [Visual C++ Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/).

Comment: It's probably worth noted that the `/permissive` flag is available since VS 2017. You could improve this answer by including the relevant quotes from the article. Like what is does, why was introduced and its relation with `/Za`