# Are objects bound to local references automatically destructed?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider the following code.

```
struct MyImage
{
    MyImage(const int handle);
    MyImage(const CString& filePath);
    virtual ~MyImage();

    void Process();
    void SaveAs(const CString& filePath);

    // No copying!
    MyImage(const MyImage& other) = delete;
    MyImage& operator=(const MyImage& other) = delete;
}

void ProcessImageFile(const CString& inFilePath, const CString& outFilePath)
{
    MyImage& image = MyImage(-1); // initialized with invalid handle

    if (DecryptionRequired())
    {
        const CString tempFilePath = ::GetTempFileName();
        Decrypt(inFilePath, tempFilePath);
        image = MyImage(tempFilePath);
        _tremove(tempFilePath);
    }
    else
    {
        image = MyImage(inFilePath);
    }

    image.Process();
    image.SaveAs(outFilePath);
}
```

Will the object referenced by `image` be destructed when `ProcessImageFile()` returns?

Comment: Note that this code is invalid in standard C++, so this is a Visual-C++ specific question.

Comment: @Brian  just for curiosity, what part is non-standard?

Comment: @tobi303 binding a non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue

Comment: @Brian yes, I was supspecting that and in the meantime Nathan wrote an answer. Looks kinda fishy, but I wasnt sure.

Comment: The title in the question is wrong. References are not destructed. Objects are destructed.

Comment: OK, it *was* wrong :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MyImage& image = MyImage(-1); // initialized with invalid handle
```

Should not compile as you cannot take a non const reference to a temporary variable.  If you had

```
const MyImage& image = MyImage(-1); // initialized with invalid handle
```

Then the liftime would be extended untill the reference's lifetime ends.  Since the reference variable is an automatic object the lifetime will end when it goes out of scope.  From [basic.stc.auto]

> Block-scope variables explicitly declared register or not explicitly declared static or extern have automatic storage duration. The storage for these entities lasts until the block in which they are created exits.

As for why Visual studio is allowing this see [Non-const reference bound to temporary, Visual Studio bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug)

Comment: when would we rather write `const MyImage& image = MyImage(-1); ` instead of `const auto image = MyImage(-1);` ?

Comment: @JohanLundberg When writing C++03 or below compatible code.

Comment: right, but what I meant was; why use a reference to hold a return value?

Comment: @JohanLundberg this is a constructor call not a function call.

Comment: IDK why the OP is doing it this way instead of `MyImage image(-1);`

Comment: I have since refactored the code to avoid using references, but I was still curious enough to ask the question.  Thank you for this informative answer.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: If you're using a factory that returns some subclass of the specified type... maybe one where the true type depends in some complex way on template parameters.

Comment: @BenVoigt; thank you. right, such as `D f(){ return D(); } ; const B& b = f(); ` where B is a base class of D. And its template generalizations.