# Update reference to object stored inside vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a std::vector with objects of the class Actor

```
std::vector<Actor>  actors(9);
```

I need to create a method which takes a single input parameter. The method should find the right Actor object in the Vector and return a reference to it. This reference will later be used by the callee to update the Object. I've tried to do this through

```
Actor& get_actor_ref_from_ped(Ped ped) {
    for (int i = 0; i < actors.size(); i++) {
        if (actors[i].isActorThisPed(ped)) {
            return actors[i];
        }
    }
    /* same issue with this approach
    for (auto &actor : actors) {
        if (actor.isActorThisPed(ped)) {
            return actor;
        }
    }*/
    //return null Actor
    return Actor::Actor();
}
```

However, when I try to update the Actor reference from another object, it behaves as if it was copied by value. Here is an example code. `actor.hasSpotLight()` is 1, but all `vectorActor.hasSpotLight()` are 0

```
void action_next_spot_light() {
    Actor actor = get_actor_ref_from_ped(PLAYER::PLAYER_PED_ID());
    if (actor.isNullActor() == false) {
        if (actor.hasSpotLight()==false) {
            actor.setHasSpotLight(true);
            log_to_file("actor.hasSpotLight() after " + std::to_string(actor.hasSpotLight()));
            for (auto &vectorActor : actors) {
                log_to_file("vectorActor.hasSpotLight() after " + std::to_string(vectorActor.hasSpotLight()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: By the way, `actor.isNullActor() == false` is better written as `!actor.isNullActor()`.

Comment: return Actor::Actor(); is undefined behavior.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Shouldn't it be a compilation error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Actor actor = get_actor_ref_from_ped(PLAYER::PLAYER_PED_ID());
```

Is going to make a copy of the value returned from the function as it calls the copy constructor.  If you want to capture the reference you need to declare a reference.

```
Actor & actor = get_actor_ref_from_ped(PLAYER::PLAYER_PED_ID());
      ^^^^^^^ reference variable
```

You also have undefined behavior in your function when you do not find an object.  `return Actor::Actor();` is returning a object that is being destroyed when the function exits.  If you want to return a empty object you could create a static object in the function and then return that as it will still exist.  For more information on why you can't return a temporary see: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Another option would be to return an iterator to the element and if no element is found then return `actors.end()`.  Then in your caller you would check if the returned iterator is equal to `actors.end()`.  This would require some rewrite.

Comment: Thank you.. was about stare myself blind at my own code and the various examples on the net

Comment: so what would the best way of returning a null Actor from the method be?

Comment: I don't understand why the OP does not get `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Actor&' from an rvalue of type 'Actor'` or `error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'Actor' to 'Actor &' A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl they could be using VS which does allow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, if you don't use `/Za`. Which has other drawbacks. Oh well...

Comment: @ChristianHackl yes, I'm using VS