# c++ error when calling method

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the following code that works in Visual Studio 10 and I want to port it on Linux -> GCC:

```
parse( v, srcUtf8.begin(), srcUtf8.end() ); <-- ERROR
```

picojson.h

```
template <typename Iter> inline std::string parse(value& out, Iter& pos, const Iter& last) 
{
 ...
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘parse(picojson::value&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)’

note: candidates are: std::string picojson::parse(picojson::value&, Iter&, const Iter&) [with Iter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]
```

Could I get please some help on this ?

Comment: How are you creating `srcUtf8`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that function `parse` has the second parameters of type  `Iter& pos` that is a non-constant reference

```
template <typename Iter> inline std::string parse(value& out, Iter& pos, const Iter& last)
```

You may not bind a non-const reference to temporary object `srcUtf8.begin()`

Try the following

```
auto it = srcUtf8.begin();
parse( v, it, srcUtf8.end() );
```

Or instead of the type specifier `auto` write the explicit type of the iterator. For example if it is an iterator of class std::string then

```
std::string::iterator it = srcUtf8.begin();
parse( v, it, srcUtf8.end() );
```

Or if  srcUtf8 is a constant object then

```
std::string::const_iterator it = srcUtf8.begin();
parse( v, it, srcUtf8.end() );
```

As for the MS VC++ 2010 then it has many bugs or its own language extensions that do not satisfy the C++ Standard.

Comment: The reason you don't need this on VS is because of this [extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug)

Comment: @Vlad thank you fro suggestion. Trying auto it = srcUtf8.begin(); I get this error:   
`Multiple markers at this line
 - cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >’ to ‘int’ in 
  initialization
 - ‘auto’ will change meaning in C++0x; please remove it
 - ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘it’ with no type`

Comment: @cristian It seems you use a compiler that does not support C++ 2011. You should switch on the supporting. Otherwise write instead of the auto std::string::iterator

Comment: @Vlad, yes, I need to use GCC 4.4.7 or older, forgot to mention that. I have made the change and it's compiling error free.  Thank you.

Comment: @NathanOliver: But VC does emit a warning if you set the appropriate warning level. Emitting a warning for ill-formed code is enough to satisy ISO-standard requirements, because the standard does not distinguish between warnings and errors (and you can make it an error with `/Za`).

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes that is true but out of the box VS will happily compile the code where g++ or clang would not.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0ba946d8f5eca89

Comment: @NathanOliver: I know, but I don't think default compiler options are that important. You always have to specify a lot of options to invoke a compiler for your specific needs and to make it interpret C++ as strictly as possible. That's true for GCC as well, which will happily swallow `int f(int x) { int a[x]; return a[0]; }` without even a single diagnostic message if you don't pass appropriate compiler options. `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and `-Wpedantic` are not even enough to make it report the proprietary extension.