# Lvalue istringstream Required for istream_iterator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, istringstream, istream-iterator, gcc5

Given a `string foo` in Visual Studio I can break the words into a `vector` by doing:

```
vector fooVec{ istream_iterator<string>(istringstream(foo)), istream_iterator<string>() };
```

But this won't compile in gcc 5.1. I get the error:

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type `std::istream_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >::istream_type&` {aka `std::basic_istream<char>&`} from an rvalue of type `std::basic_istream<char>`

Now I know that gcc had [a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316) that was fixed by our own [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely). Is this an extension of that bug or should it be illegal for me to use an Rvalue `istringstream` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a gcc bug but an [evil MSVC extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug).  [`std::istream_iterator::istream_iteraor()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator) requires an lvalue reference.  Since `istringstream(foo)` is a temporary gcc correctly tells you you cannot bind the temporary to the lvalue reference.

The reason this works on MSVC is that previously mentioned extension that allows temporaries to be bound to lvalue references.  This allows the non standard compliant code to work on MSVC.

So to answer

> Is this an extension of that bug or should it be illegal for me to use an Rvalue `istringstream` here?

No this is not a bug and you need a non-temporary stream here to construct the `istream_iterator`.