gcc and clang cannot use a non const iterator as "reference to const_iterator"
The following program gives an error on the indicated line when compiled with clang and gcc. However the same program compiles and runs fine in MSVC.
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void f(std::string::const_iterator& p)
{
    ++p;
}

int main ()
{
    std::string s{"ABCD"};

    std::string::const_iterator ps = s.begin();
    f(ps);
    std::cout <<"ps= " << *ps <<std::endl;

    std::string::iterator qs = s.begin();
    f(qs);                    //<--- clang and gcc report an error here
    std::cout <<"qs= " << *qs <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}

What is the correct behavior according to language standard?
My personal opinion is that MSVC is right in this situation. Note that in the line, ps = s.begin();, all compilers correctly convert from non-const iterator to const iterator. The same rules should apply for references.
Follow up question: if gcc and clang are correct, how can I pass a non const iterator reference to a function requiring a const iterator reference?
EDIT:
Thank you all for your comments! Now I understand why, in general, it should not work and why, in the particular case of MSVC, it works.
One solution to my problem could be to add an overload function:
inline void f(std::string::iterator& p)
{
  f(*(std::string::const_iterator*)(&p));
}


Non const lvalue references cannot be bound to an lvalue of different type

My personal opinion is that MSVC is right in this situation It is not.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37546443/lvalue-istringstream-required-for-istream-iterator/37546565#37546565

I wouldn't have expected this to work even in MSVC, I though in the second call to f the argument would refer to a copy, the result of an implicit conversion, and changing the copy wouldn't affect qs. But it appears to work : https://godbolt.org/z/Yc6z3vco8 I'm curious what rules MSVC is using.

What is confusing me is all the ways suggested to get MSVS to not compile this code do not work: https://godbolt.org/z/TKP5qT3en

For your follow-up question, make a copy like in your std::string::const_iterator ps = s.begin(); and then pass ps to the function. Unless you have some complex logic that sometimes needs input iterator, and sometimes output iterator.

The  MSVC implementation derives iterator from const_iterator, which is one way of making them convertible. 

I think iterators are intended to be passed by copy - given that they themselves provide the indirection. Passing a reference will likely end up with a double indirection which maybe be less efficient.

References, by their nature, have to be exact.  You can't make a reference to a related type unless that type can stand in for the other (i.e. is a child type).

const_iterator and iterator may be distinct unrelated class types, but do not have to be.
If so it is not possible to bind an lvalue of one of them to a non-const lvalue reference of the other. Only const lvalue references can bind (to a temporary object created by conversion) in such a case.
But alternatively there could be an inheritance relationship between the two types or the two types could simply be pointer types. In these cases it may be possible that a const_iterator lvalue reference binds to a iterator lvalue.
So both behaviors are conforming to the standard.


One solution to my problem could be to add an overload function:

That overload causes undefined behavior. You are effectively doing a reinterpret_cast between unrelated types. Any use of the result will be UB because the resulting pointer can't actually point to an object of target type since there is none.
You can't forward from the const_iterator case to the iterator case. You need to write the function twice or use a function template.
Note that the UB is not because of potential different data layouts between iterator and const_iterator. Even if these types are implemented with exactly the same class layout, it is still UB and compilers do make use of this in practice for aliasing analysis. For a practical example in which the UB manifests as unintended output see e.g. the following extension of your example
https://godbolt.org/z/fP6bEnf39
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void f(std::string::const_iterator& p, std::string::iterator& q)
{
    ++p;
    ++q;
    ++p;
}

inline void f(std::string::iterator& p, std::string::iterator& q)
{
  f(*(std::string::const_iterator*)(&p), q);
}

int main ()
{
    std::string s{"ABCD"};

    std::string::iterator qs = s.begin();
    f(qs, qs);
    std::cout <<"qs= " << *qs <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}

The iterator is incremented thrice, so the result should naively be qs= D, but both GCC and Clang output qs= C with optimizations enabled. The compilers assume that p and q in f can't refer to the same object because if they did, then either ++q or ++p would attempt to call a non-static member function with incorrect unrelated type, which is UB.

True enough. However all major compilers (GCC, clang, MSVC) seem to use the same binary layout for iterator and const_iterator. I'll have to live with that for the moment.

@Mircea It is not only about the binary layout. Even if they are exactly the same, then it is still UB and compilers do make use of that for optimization (specifically pointer aliasing analysis). It is never safe to cast between pointers to unrelated types like this (with only a handful of specific exceptions).

@Mircea Practical example where UB manifests with enabled optimization: https://godbolt.org/z/Wcjd87n3f

very cool example. It puts me between a rock and a hard place: the f function in my real world application is a long, rather complicated function that calls on other functions that need not to be visible. That makes templating it rather unpleasant. On the other hand just repeating the code with a different signature makes for bloated code. Not fun!

@Mircea Because you know that there are only two relevant types, you can define the templated function in a .cpp file just like the non-template variant and use explicit instantiation for the two types, instead of following the other (more common) approach of defining the template in a header file and relying on implicit instantiation. That way you won't increase dependencies and wont need to make anything new visible.
