# c++ compilation error in linux

Tags: c++, linux

My code runs in a Windows environment with Visual Studio but does not seem to compile in Linux. I have been troubleshooting for a very long time but cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong.

The errors in my programs read "error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Edge&' from an rvalue of type 'Edge'

What I don't understand is why Linux seems to have an issue with it, as it is not syntactically incorrect since it does compile in a Windows environment. What is it I need to change for this thing to run on Linux?

I have included what I think is the relevant code for one of the programs, the first one in the link, since the other has the same errors.

EDIT: I am using g++ to compile my code in Linux. If you need any other information, please let me know since I don't know what information may be relevant based on the error message and my inexperience with Linux.

command line errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iY2I.jpg

Graph.h:

```
#ifndef _H_GRAPH_H
#define _H_GRAPH_H

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Hashtable.h"
#include <sstream>
#include "Vertex.h"
#include "LinkedStack.h"
#include "LinkedQueue.h"
#include "IllegalArgumentException.h"
using namespace std;

#define INFINITY 1000000

template <class T>
class Graph{

public:
    //constructor
    Graph(){
        numVertices = 0;
    }
//destructor
~Graph(){}
///////////////////////////Accessors//////////////////
//Returns true if the graph is empty, false otherwise
bool empty() const{
    return numVertices == 0;
}
//Returns the indegree of the vertex v. Throw
//an illegal argument exception if the argument does not correspond to an existing vertex.
int indegree(string v){
    Vertex<T>* vertex = hashtable.get(v);
    if (vertex == NULL)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    LinkedList<Vertex<T>*> linkedlist;
    hashtable.getVertices(linkedlist);

    int count = 0;
    //iterate the list 
    LinkedListNode<Vertex<T>*>* ll = linkedlist.getHead();
    while(ll != NULL)
    {
        //iterate the list of edges
        LinkedListNode< Edge<T> >* llEdges = ll->data->getEdges().getHead();
        while(llEdges != NULL){

            Vertex<T>* pv = llEdges->data.getTo();
            if (pv == vertex)
            {
                count++;
            }               

            llEdges = llEdges->next;
        }
        ll = ll->next;
    }//end while
    return count;
}

//Returns the outdegree of the vertex v. Throw
//an illegal argument exception if the argument does not correspond to an existing vertex.
int outdegree(string v){

    Vertex<T>* vertex = hashtable.get(v);
    if (vertex == NULL)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return vertex->getOutdegree();
}

//Returns the number of edges of the vertex v.
int edgeCount(string v){
    Vertex<T>* vertex = hashtable.get(v);
    if (vertex == NULL)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return vertex->getEdges().size();
}

//Returns the number of edges in the graph
int edgeCount(){
    LinkedList<Vertex<T>*> linkedlist;
    hashtable.getVertices(linkedlist);

    int count = 0;
    //iterate the list 
    LinkedListNode<Vertex<T>*>* ll = linkedlist.getHead();
    while(ll != NULL)
    {
        count += ll->data->getEdges().size();
        ll = ll->next;
    }
    return count;
}

//Returns the weight
//of the edge connecting vertices u and v. If the vertices are the same, return 0.
//If the vertices are not adjacent, return infinity (your representation of infinity).
//Throw an illegal argument exception if the arguments do not correspond to
//existing vertices.
double adjacent( string u, string v ){
    Vertex<T>* pu = hashtable.get(u);
    Vertex<T>* pv = hashtable.get(v);
    if (pv == NULL || pu == NULL)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    //iterate the list 
    LinkedListNode< Edge<T> >* ll = pu->getEdges().getHead();
    while(ll != NULL)
    {
        if (ll->data.getTo() == pv)
        {
            return ll->data.getWeight();
        }
        ll = ll->next;
    }
    return INFINITY;
}

//Performs DFS traversal starting on vertex v.
//Reset vertices after the traversal.
void DFS(string v){
    Vertex<T>* pv = hashtable.get(v);
    if (pv == NULL)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    LinkedStack<Vertex<T>*> stack;
    stack.push(pv);

    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {           
        Vertex<T> *u = NULL;
        try{
            u = stack.pop();
        }catch(StackEmptyException &e){
            cout << e.what() << endl;
        }

        if (!u->isVisited())
        {
            u->setVisited(true);

            //visit it
            cout << u->getName() << " " << u->getData() << endl;

            //check its neigbours
            //iterate the list 
            LinkedListNode< Edge<T> >* llEdges = u->getEdges().getHead();
            while(llEdges != NULL){

                if (llEdges->data.getTo()->isVisited() == false)
                {
                    stack.push(llEdges->data.getTo());
                }               

                llEdges = llEdges->next;
            }
        }

    }//end while

    //Reset vertices after the traversal.
    reset();
}

//Performs BFS traversal starting on vertex v.
//Reset vertices after the traversal.
void BFS(string v){
    Vertex<T>* pv = hashtable.get(v);
    if (pv == NULL)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    LinkedQueue<Vertex<T>*> queue;
    queue.enqueue(pv);

    while (!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        Vertex<T> *u = NULL;
        try{
            u = queue.dequeue();
        }catch(QueueEmptyException &e){
            cout << e.what() << endl;
        }

        if (!u->isVisited())
        {
            u->setVisited(true);

            //visit it
            cout << u->getName() << " " << u->getData() << endl;

            //check its neigbours
            //iterate the list 
            LinkedListNode< Edge<T> >* llEdges = u->getEdges().getHead();
            while(llEdges != NULL){

                if (!llEdges->data.getTo()->isVisited())
                {
                    queue.enqueue(llEdges->data.getTo());
                }               

                llEdges = llEdges->next;
            }
        }
    }//end while

    //Reset vertices after the traversal.
    reset();
}

//Determines if u and v are connected
bool isConnected(Vertex<T>* v, Vertex<T>* u){
    LinkedList< Vertex<T>* > visitedList;
    LinkedList< Vertex<T>* > ll;
    ll.add(v);

    while (ll.size() > 0)
    {
        Vertex<T>* temp = ll.getHead()->data;
        ll.remove(ll.getHead()->data);

        visitedList.add(temp);

        //iterate the list 
        LinkedListNode< Edge<T> >* llEdges = temp->getEdges().getHead();
        while(llEdges != NULL){

             Vertex<T>* pv = llEdges->data.getTo();
            if (pv == u)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (visitedList.contains(pv) == false)
            {
                ll.add(pv);
            }               

            llEdges = llEdges->next;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

//find the vertex that has next min key (distance)
//set the new key(distance) if it is shorter
Vertex<T>* processNextMinVertex(Vertex<T>* current){
    Vertex<T>* u = NULL;        

    //iterate neibours from current
    LinkedListNode< Edge<T> >* llEdge = current->getEdges().getHead();
    while (llEdge != NULL)
    {
        u = llEdge->data.getTo();
        double newKey = current->getKey() + llEdge->data.getWeight() ;

        if (u->isVisited() == false)
        {
            if (newKey < u->getKey())
            {
                u->setKey(newKey);
                u->setPrevVertex(current);
            }
        }

        llEdge = llEdge->next;
    }

    double min = INFINITY;
    LinkedList<Vertex<T>*> linkedlist;
    hashtable.getVertices(linkedlist);

    //find min unvisited node
    //iterate that list of vertice
    LinkedListNode<Vertex<T>*>* ll = linkedlist.getHead();
    while (ll != NULL)
    {
        if (ll->data->isVisited() == false && min > ll->data->getKey())
        {
            min = ll->data->getKey();
            u = ll->data;
        }   
        ll = ll->next;
    }
    return u;
}

//shortPath( string u, string v ) (20 points) Returns the shortest path
//between vertices u and v. Throw an illegal argument exception if the arguments
//do not correspond to existing vertices.
void shortPath(string u, string v){
    reset();//reset

    //reset previous vertices
    resetPrevVertices();

    Vertex<T>* pu = hashtable.get(u);
    if (pu == NULL)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    Vertex<T>* pv = hashtable.get(v);
    if (pv == NULL)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    //check if them connected
    if (!isConnected(pu, pv))
    {
        cout << "Vertices are not connected" << endl;
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    Vertex<T>* current = pu; //current checking vertex
    Vertex<T>* nextVertex; //next min vertex
    current->setKey(0);//starting vertex

    while (current != pv)
    {
        current->setVisited(true);
        nextVertex = processNextMinVertex(current);
        current = nextVertex;
    }//end while

    //print shortest path
    stringstream ss;
    ss << current->getName() << " " << current->getData();
    current = current->getPrevVertex();
    //iterate to source
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        ss << " -> " << current->getName() << " " << current->getData();
        current = current->getPrevVertex();
    }

    //print path
    cout << ss.str() << endl;

    //Reset vertices
    reset();
}

//Returns the shortest
//distance between vertices u and v. Throw an illegal argument exception if the
//arguments do not correspond to existing vertices. The distance between a vertex
//and itself is 0.0. The distance between vertices that are not connected is innity.
double distance( string u, string v ){
    reset();//reset

    //reset previous vertices
    resetPrevVertices();

    Vertex<T>* pu = hashtable.get(u);
    if (pu == NULL)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    Vertex<T>* pv = hashtable.get(v);
    if (pv == NULL)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    //check if them connected
    if (!isConnected(pu, pv))
    {
        cout << "Vertices are not connected" << endl;
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    Vertex<T>* current = pu; //current checking vertex
    Vertex<T>* nextVertex; //next min vertex
    current->setKey(0);//starting vertex

    while (current != pv)
    {
        current->setVisited(true);
        nextVertex = processNextMinVertex(current);
        current = nextVertex;
    }//end while

    double shortestDistance = current->getKey();

    //Reset vertices
    reset();

    return shortestDistance;
}
///////////////////////////Mutators///////////////////
//Reads structure from a text file and builds a undirected weighted graph.
void buildGraph(string filename){
    ifstream infile;

    //data of file
    int numberOfVertices; //number of vertices
    int numberOfEdges; //number of edges
    string name; //name of vertex
    double data; //data of vertex
    string from, to; //for edge
    double weight;

    //open file for reading
    infile.open(filename.c_str());

    //check input file
    if(infile.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Could not open the file " << filename << endl;
        return;
    }

    //read first 2 numbers
    infile >> numberOfVertices;
    infile >> numberOfEdges;

    //read the vertices 
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++)
    {
        infile >> name;
        infile >> data;
        hashtable.put(new Vertex<double>(name, data));
    }//end  for

    //read the edges 
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEdges; i++)
    {
        infile >> from;
        infile >> to;
        infile >> weight;
        try{
            insert(from, to, weight);
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException &e){
            cout << e.what() << endl;
        }
    }//end  for

    //close input file
    infile.close();

    numVertices = numberOfVertices;
}

//Removes all the elements in the undirected weighted graph
void clear(){
    numVertices = 0;
    hashtable.clear();
}

//Iterates over all vertices in the graph and marks them
//as unvisited.
void reset(){
    //iterate the list 
    LinkedList<Vertex<T>*> linkedlist;
    hashtable.getVertices(linkedlist);
    LinkedListNode<Vertex<T>*>* ll = linkedlist.getHead();
    while(ll != NULL)
    {
        ll->data->setVisited(false);
        ll->data->setKey(INFINITY);
        ll = ll->next;
    }
}

//Iterates over all vertices in the graph and reset previous vertex
void resetPrevVertices(){
    //iterate the list 
    LinkedList<Vertex<T>*> linkedlist;
    hashtable.getVertices(linkedlist);
    LinkedListNode<Vertex<T>*>* ll = linkedlist.getHead();
    while(ll != NULL)
    {
        ll->data->setPrevVertex(NULL);
        ll = ll->next;
    }
}

//If the weight w < 0
//or w = 1, throw an illegal argument exception. If the weight w is 0, remove
//any edge between u and v (if any). Otherwise, add an edge between vertices u
//and v with weight w. If an edge already exists, replace the weight of the edge
//with the new weight. If the vertices do not exist or are equal, throw an illegal
//argument exception.
void insert(string u, string v, double w){
    if (w < 0 || w == 1)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Vertex<T>* pu = hashtable.get(u);
    Vertex<T>* pv = hashtable.get(v);

    //If the vertices do not exist or are equal, throw an illegal
    //argument exception.
    if (pv == NULL || pu == NULL || pv == pu)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (w == 0)//remove edge
    {
        //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Edge<double>&' from an rvalue of type 'Edge<double>'
        pu->getEdges().remove(Edge<T>(pu, pv, 0));
    }else{
        //add edge
        pu->getEdges().add(Edge<T>(pu, pv, w));
    }
}

//Removes vertex v from the graph, and updates
//connections in the graph.
void del(string v){
    Vertex<T>* pv = hashtable.get(v);

    //If the vertex do not exist throw an illegal
    //argument exception.
    if (pv == NULL)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    hashtable.del(v);
}
private:
    Hashtable<T> hashtable;
    int numVertices;
};


#endif
```

Main.cpp:

```
/*
 The program implements the menu based program 
 that allows user to use graph functions
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Graph.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream> 
using namespace std;

//read an integer
int readInt(string prompt){
    string input;
    stringstream ss;

    //prompt for input
    cout << prompt;
    getline(cin, input);

    //push to stream
    ss << input;

    int intNumber;
    ss >> intNumber;

    return intNumber;
}

//read a double
double readDouble(string prompt){
    string input;
    stringstream ss;

    //prompt for input
    cout << prompt;
    getline(cin, input);

    //push to stream
    ss << input;

    double intNumber;
    ss >> intNumber;

    return intNumber;
}

//build graph from text file
void buildGraph(Graph<double> &graph){
    string filename = "input.txt";
    //cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    //getline(cin, filename);

    graph.buildGraph(filename);
}

int main(){
    string name, name2; //name of vertex
    Graph<double> MSTGraph; //minimum spanning tree
    //define graph
    Graph<double> graph;
    int option = -1;

    //build graph
    try{
        buildGraph(graph);
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException &e){
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }   

    while (option != 0)
    {
        //display menu
        cout << "1. Check empty" << endl;
        cout << "2. Get indegree" << endl;
        cout << "3. Get outdegree" << endl;
        cout << "4. Edge count of graph" << endl;
        cout << "5. DFS" << endl;
        cout << "6. BFS" << endl;
        cout << "7. shortest path" << endl;
        cout << "8. distance" << endl;
        cout << "0. Exit" << endl;

        option = readInt("Your selection? ");

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1://Check empty
            cout << "Graph is empty?" << graph.empty() << endl;
            break;
        case 2://Get indegree
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            try{
                cout << "Degree = " << graph.indegree(name);
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException &e){
                cout << e.what() << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 3://Get outdegree
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            try{
                cout << "Degree = " << graph.outdegree(name);
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException &e){
                cout << e.what() << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 4://Edge count of graph
            cout << "Edge count of graph = " << graph.edgeCount() << endl;
            break;
        case 5://DFS
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            try{
                graph.DFS(name);
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException &e){
                cout << e.what() << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 6://BFS
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            try{
                graph.BFS(name);
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException &e){
                cout << e.what() << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 7://short path
            cout << "Enter first name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            cout << "Enter second name: ";
            getline(cin, name2);

            try{
                graph.shortPath(name, name2);
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException &e){
                cout << e.what() << endl;
            }           
            break;
        case 8://distance
            cout << "Enter first name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            cout << "Enter second name: ";
            getline(cin, name2);

            try{
                cout << "The shortest distance is " << graph.distance(name, name2) << endl;             
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException &e){
                cout << e.what() << endl;
            }           
            break;
        case 0:
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid selection" << endl;
            break;
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't have the time to find it in your code but it works with MSVS because of this [evil extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug)

Comment: Please don't link *images* of compiler errors - simply copy/paste the text of the errors, and include those directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer a question like this without knowing a lot more information. It might not even have to do with Linux if you are using a different compiler for the job for example.

What is your whole toolchain? Are you using GCC? G++? MingW?

Also, do you know for sure the error is happening in the code you provided and not somewhere in one of the included files?

That being said...

Here is a good [explanation](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) of lvalue and rvalue, maybe reading up on the features of post c++11 features might help you narrow down your question and figure out exactly where the code is breaking down for you in Linux, giving us a better ability to help you.