# Why does this work on Windows and break when I compile on Linux?

Tags: c++, stream

I'm writing a console application for managing and tracking characters, monsters, turn order and conditions applied to make my battle run faster in DnD. The following code works perfectly on Windows but when I tried to compile it on my laptop, which runs Linux, it no longer works.

I input a name, then the initiative, then max health, then when I go to add another character it just reads a blank string and sets that as the name. I'm at a loss...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void gValid_Input(std::string& var, std::string question = "Add the carriage return manually if you want it...") {
    using namespace std;

    do {
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        cout << question;
    } while (!getline(cin, var));
}

template <typename t>
void gValid_Input(t& var, std::string question = "Add the carriage return manually if you want it...") {
    using namespace std;

    do {
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        cout << question;
    } while (!(cin >> var));
}

void gValid_Option(char& response, std::vector<char> valid_Responses = {'y','n'}){
    using namespace std;
    const char diff = 'a' - 'A';

    do{
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        cin >> response;

        if (response >= 'A' && response <= 'Z'){
            response += diff;
        }

    } while (find(valid_Responses.begin(), valid_Responses.end(), response) == valid_Responses.end());
}

void gValid_Option(char& response, std::string question, std::vector<char> valid_Responses = {'y','n'}){
    using namespace std;
    const char diff = 'a' - 'A';

    do{
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        cout << question;
        cin >> response;

        if (response >= 'A' && response <= 'Z'){
            response += diff;
        }

    } while (find(valid_Responses.begin(), valid_Responses.end(), response) == valid_Responses.end());
}
```

SOLVED

```
void gValid_Input(std::string& var, std::string question = "Add the carriage return manually if you want it...") {
    using namespace std;

    do {
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        cout << question;
        if (cin.peak() == '\n'){
            cin.ignore(1, '\n');
        }
    } while (!getline(cin, var));
}
```

Comment: @konijn is correct, stackoverflow is a better place to ask this. Are you using Visual Studio, and if so did you specify C++ standard?

Comment: I have a felling it may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug) but without a [mcve] and a description of what *no longer works* is, it is hard to tell.

Comment: @pacmaninbw using code::blocks 16.01 using the supplies mingw compiler and set to compile according to c++14

Comment: I suggest using `tolower()` or `toupper()` rather than using `'a' - 'A'`.  Your letter subtraction may be based on a false assumption.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No assumptions made, C++ uses ascii I looked it up on the ascii chart.

Comment: @NathanOliver good guess on the first one, but I'm using g++ on both systems to compile my code....

what happens is I get a string, then an int, then an unsigned int, then a char then when I try to get another string it sets a blank string. But only on linux.