# Unable to use operator<< for anonymous object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, parameter-passing

In my code below, I am creating a class that takes in variables using operator<< and processes the variables accordingly. The exact logic that will go inside the class is omitted for simplicity & clarity.

The issue that I'm facing is that when I try to create an anonymous instance of the object, and use that directly with the (<<) operator, most compilers would complain - something along the lines of *(no match for 'operator<<')*

From what I understand, calling the class directly ( *TestObject()* ) is a legal expression, and it should instantiate an anonymous object that gets passed into the operator.

Appreciate your thoughts on why this does not compile?

```
typedef unsigned int uint32;

class TestObject
{
public:
   TestObject()
      : mValue(0)
   {
   }

   uint32 GetValue() const
   {
      return mValue;
   }

private:
   uint32 mValue;
};

template <typename T>
TestObject& operator<<(TestObject& o, const T& t)
{
   return o;
}

void TestObjectTest()
{
   TestObject myTestObject;
   uint32 newValue = 123;
   const uint32 resultValue = (myTestObject << newValue).GetValue(); // This compiles for both visual studio 2013 and gcc.
   const uint32 resultValue2 = (TestObject() << newValue).GetValue(); // Compiles using visual studio 2013, but does not compile using x86-64 gcc 6.2: "no match for 'operator<<' in 'TestObject() << newValue'
}

int main(void)
{
    TestObjectTest();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldnt be able to bind a temporary to a non const reference I'm surprised that compiles in VS

Answer (score 3):

`TestObject()` yields a temporary `TestObject`.  Since it is not a temporary you cannot bind it to a lvalue reference ([except for MSVS's evil extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug)).  If your operator does not need to modify the `TestObject` then simply changing it to take a `const&` is enough:

```
template <typename T>
const TestObject& operator<<(const TestObject& o, const T& t)
{
   return o;
}
```

If you need to modify the value then you need to add another overload and take in a rvalue reference.  That will bind to the temporary and allow you to modify it:

```
template <typename T>
TestObject& operator<<(TestObject&& o, const T& t)
{
   return o;
}
```

Comment: Beware that the first solution need explicit cast to remove constness on return.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Good call.  I just changed it to return a `const &`.

Comment: Is it valid to return a reference to an rvalue reference parameter? Won't this be a "dangling" reference when the temporary argument gets destroyed?

Comment: @zett42 Not it is not.  I forgot about that.  It should work now.

Comment: @zett42 Actually I think you have to return it by reference if you want to chain it.  The standard streams do the same thing.  I think it is safe as long as at the end you don't yourself capture the returned reference.