# Release memory of std::vector in VC++ 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I've recently started upgrading my current projects from VS2015 to VS2019 and VS2019 is a lot more restrictive about some things. One thing I have an issue with in particular is the way I'm currently releasing the memory of vectors:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
v.swap(std::vector<int>()); // v should now be empty with no memory held
```

This worked fine in VS2015 but in VS2019 it no longer works because the vector I swap with is constant and `vector::swap()` requires a reference. This behavior has changed recently and must be a problem for more people than me given that this is the recommended way of releasing the memory of a vector. MS docs on the issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2664?view=msvc-160

What is the new recommended way of releasing the memory of a vector if you can't swap it away?

Comment: Are you looking for `clear()` and `shrink_to_fit()`? Or you can simply ***assign*** an empty vector to this existing object, `v=std::vector<int>{};`, no fancy swapping was ever needed to do this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `clear()` does not actually release the memory held by the vector and `shrink_to_fit()` is implementation defined so you can't trust that it will release the memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your doing it backwards.  To clear and release the memory for a vector in a guaranteed way, declare a temporary vector and swap the vector that needs to be cleared into it.  That would tun your code into

```
std::vector<int>{}.swap(v);
```

At the end of the expression, the temporary object will be destroyed, taking the memory of `v` with it.

---

The reason this work before is Microsoft had an [evil extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug) that was on by default that allowed prvalues to bind to non-const lvalue references.  With that extension no longer on, the old non-standard code is now rightly failing to compile.

Comment: Why are you using `{}` brackets instead of `()` in `std::vector<int>{}.swap(v);` ?

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha, it's a way of doing constructor calls to avoid most vexing parse issues. Even when MVP wouldn't be an issue, good to stick with `{}` for consistency.

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha It doesn't really matter but I tend to use `{}` for temporary objects to make them look less like a function.

Answer (score 1):

> vector I swap with is constant

It's not constant, but it's an anonymous temporary, so it can only bind to a const ref.

> What is the new recommended way of releasing the memory of a vector if you can't swap it away?

Well, you *can* swap it away, if you want to stay backwards compatible and/or don't trust `shrink_to_fit()`. You just have to name your temporary:

```
{
  std::vector<int> tmp;
  v.swap(tmp);
}
```

(obviously the reversed anonymous swap in the other answer is neater, if you don't need to stay backwards-compatible with C++98).