# saving a lambda expression as parameter/variable inside a class to another class

Tags: c++, class, lambda

I made a class and a struct.

The class is named `Learning` and the struct is named `Action`.

My `Action` constructor takes one parameter: object's function, and the function is a `std::function<int(int)>`.

This is my `Action` struct:

```cpp
typedef std::function<int(int)> func;

struct Action {
    // constructor
    Action(func);

    /// methods
    /// operators
    int operator()(int x);

    /// members
    func f;
};

Action(func f) {this->f = f; }
```

My `Action` struct is used by my `Learning` class by calling this function:

```cpp
class Learning
{
public:
    void addAction(Action);
    Action getAction(int idx);
private:
    std::vector<Action> actions;
};

void Learning::addAction(Action act)
{
    actions.push_back(act);
}

int Learning::getAction(int idx)
{
   return actions[idx];
}

int main(){
Learning robot;
robot.addAction(Action([](int y) ->int{return y++; }));
std::cout << robot.getAction(0)(0) << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Where the `Action` is saved inside an `actions` vector in my `Learning` class:

The method `addAction()` adds the created `Action` object into my `actions` vector. another method 'getAction(idx)' is used to call one action from action vector.

I used a lambda expression as the parameter because it looks cleaner.

But when I call `robot.getAction(0)(0)`, or `actions[0](0)` inside the class, I get an exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA4DE44F69 in RL_Q.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_function_call at memory location 0x000000C09A7BE4C0.
```

When I debug this, my function `f` is empty after I instantiate my `Action` object with given parameters.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] for us?

Comment: Not the crashing issue but `return y++;` returns the original value of `y`. Just `return y+1;` no need for anything fancy.

Comment: I suspect that this isn't your real code, as `void Learning::addAction(Action& act)` will not accept the r-value (temporary) that you claim to be passing to it.  A [mre] is likely necessary to answer this question.

Comment: my ```void Learning::addAction(Action& act)``` is an lvalue. the rvalue is inside the constructor Action();

Comment: @ZainAhmed `addAction()` takes a non-const lvalue reference for its parameter, so it will NOT accept a temporary object as input, as you have shown. The compile fails: "*cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Action&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Action’*".  To accept a temporary object, the parameter needs to take either a const lvalue reference (`const Action&`), or an rvalue reference (`Action&&`).

Comment: This is Visual Studio's fault, thanks to a "language extension" that allows binding temporaries to non-`const` references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug

Comment: Even so, the `push_back()` should be making a *copy* of the passed `Action`, even if the original is a temporary.

Comment: @ZainAhmed do you have the same problem if you change the `Action` constructor to take `func` by value instead of by const reference? `Action(name, func)`. Also, is the `Action` constructor even assigning the `f` member? You didn't show the constructor implementation

Comment: sorry this is my constructor:

```
RL::Action::Action(name name, func func)
{
 setname(name);
 setfunction(func);
}

where setname is a function that set name and setfunction sets the f
```

Comment: @ZainAhmed please add the relevant code in your question, not in the comments

Comment: I have added the code, but your solution didn't work for me. my f I still empty when I call f from my action vector

Comment: This question is still missing a [mre].  We can not reproduce the problem you are describing, so any answer would be a guess.  Maybe there's a problem with `setname`?  Or with `setfunction`?  Those are guesses about code we can not see.

Comment: the setfunction could be problem here.

but when i run the program I get an exception

Comment: setname and setfunction arent the issue here.

the issue is accessing the function from the action vector, will give an empty function and results an exception despite I've defined it with my lambda expression.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You define

```
Learning::addAction(Action&)
```

with an action reference as argument. This means that you have to ensure the lifetime of the referenced object, and not let it get destroyed by going out of scope. But then you call it on an rvalue

```
// Action(...) immediately goes out of scope
robot.addAction(Action("Up", [](int y) ->int{return y++; }));
```

Therefore the references you put in your vectors are all invalid : they point toward long gone objects. You need to take ownership of them if you want it to work. This means :

```
class Learning
{  
  public:
    void addAction(Action&&);
  private:
    std::vector<Action> actions;
};

// rvalue reference, so the vector can take ownership of the expiring object
void Learning::addAction(Action&& act)
{
  actions.push_back(std::move(act));
}
```

Comment: The OP's code shouldn't even compile, since a temporary object can't bind to a non-const lvalue reference like `Action&`, only to a const lvalue reference like `const Action&` or to an rvalue reference like `Action&&`. In any case, the OP's `addAction()` is calling the overload of `vector::push_back()` that takes in an lvalue reference, so it will *make a copy* of the passed `Action` object, so the lifetime of the original `Action` is not a factor here. But you are correct that using move semantics would be a better design.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I disagree, an rvalue like Action(...) cannot be bound to an lvalue reference like Action&. The fact that it calls push_back internally does not change anything to the way addAction is called (erroneously)
Edit : I agree with your edit

Comment: "*an rvalue like Action(...) cannot be bound to an lvalue reference like Action&.*" - that is exactly what I said in my previous comment. As for `push_back()`, inside of `addAction()`, the `act` parameter is an lvalue, even if passed in an rvalue, so `push_back(act)` will call the lvalue version that makes a copy, not the rvalue version that performs a move, that requires `push_back(std::move(act))`, as you showed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I now agree 100% with you, and had written my comment before seeing that you had updated yours. I'll delete this answer which is plain wrong

Comment: Your solution is correct, it is just your explanation of the problem that is wrong.

Comment: Um I got the problem because when i use std::move I get std::move<Action&> returned

I can't call the functions of the actions vector. every time I call actions[I].f(0), I get an exception.

Comment: I tried with vs code, and it somehow worked for me. I guess when used class for my header file, that's where the problem starts...

Answer (score 0):

Your addAction method takes a reference

```
void addAction(Action&);
```

Then you call this with an rvalue

```
robot.addAction(Action("Up", [](int y) ->int{return y++; }));
```

You can not bind an rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference. Either make the method const ref or rvalue reference.

```
void addAction(const Action&);
void addAction(Action&&);
```

Comment: This does explain why a C++ compiler can rightfully reject compiling this code, although I don't think this answers the question asked here.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, you only pointed out errors. I get it, but this isn't the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @ZainAhmed Your question was: "How do I solve this?" And in the last code snippet I gave you the answer.

Comment: @Bako I did try your code snippet, but that did not work. I suggest give me more alternative answer.