# Ternary operator with implicit conversion of lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, conditional-operator

```
int x = 100;
int& f() { return x; }
auto g = []() mutable -> int& { return x; };
std::function<int&()> funcfunc()
{
    std::cin >> x;
    int& (&h)() = x > 0 ? f : g;
    return h;
}
```

Somehow it compiles with `MSVC`, while `clang` and `gcc` believe g could not convert to int&(*)() and then be used to initialize h with type 'int&(&)()'

Comment: What version of MSVS are you using?  `g` should decay into a prvalue function pointer, so you should not be able to bind a non-const lvalue reference to it.  related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug

Comment: This should probably be written `if (x > 0) return f; else return g;`. (there seems to be a rash of ternary operator abuse lately...)

Comment: On godbolt it compiles only if C++20 is activated: https://godbolt.org/z/hc6oE5vWj with C++17 MSVC reports an error too.

Comment: And here is fixed version: https://godbolt.org/z/Mab9jr1Wc (compiles everywhere). Reference to a function doesn't make seance anyway.